# nginx service is not starting (error = (code=exited, status=150))

Tags: networking, services, nginx

i make a service and trying to start it ,but showing following error.my nginx is in active status.

error = (code=exited, status=150)
i had tried-reinstall the nignx and recreate the service.

detailed error is given below.

```
root@amit-OptiPlex-3050:/# sudo systemctl enable CoreApplication.service
root@amit-OptiPlex-3050:/# sudo systemctl start CoreApplication.service
root@amit-OptiPlex-3050:/# sudo systemctl status CoreApplication.service
● CoreApplication.service - CoreApplication .NET Core App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/CoreApplication.service; enabled; vendor 
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-03 18
  Process: 15432 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/newwebapps/CoreApplication/CoreA
 Main PID: 15432 (code=exited, status=150)
lines 1-5/5 (END)...skipping...
● CoreApplication.service - CoreApplication .NET Core App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/CoreApplication.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-03 18:13:31 IST; 1s ago
  Process: 15432 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/newwebapps/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.dll ***(code=exited, status=150)***
 Main PID: 15432 (code=exited, status=150)
```

Comment: What process is this and what is it supposed to be doing and how is it connected to nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar error and I ran the command in the service file:
/usr/bin/dotnet /path/to/dotnetcore.dll

The result was: 
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.6' was not found.

Probably you are missing the correct framework.